# ¿Cómo hago un salto de linea cada 10 caracteres de un array con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, salto-de-linea

tengo un controlador en javaScript y este me trae un arreglo de texto con un max de 50 caracteres y necesito que cada 10 caracteres este realice un salto de linea "/n" para mostrarlo en pantalla con 5 parrafos en este caso, agradezco sus ayudas.

Comment: Hola! Cuál cntrolador? Cuál arreglo? Cómo intentaste resolver tu problema? Qué falló? Con qué datos probaste? Edita tu pregunta e incluye toda esta info para que recibas una respuesta pronto

Comment: Hola, las preguntas del tipo "tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar nada de código, o sin mostrar que has intentado hacer algo por tu cuenta son mal recibidas. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y también como hacer un 
[Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), esto para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví, Gracias...

```
var texto2 = text[w];
textOBS += "                     >";
                                        
for(var x = 0; x < texto2.length; x++){
    if(x == 10){
       textOBS += texto2[x];
       textOBS += "\n";
    else{
       textOBS += texto2[x];    
    }
}
```

Lo que realice fue tomar el valor del arreglo, crear un ciclo para recorrer letra por letra y hacer la condición donde necesitaba que se hiciera el salto de línea que en este caso era el carácter 10, si se cumple esta condición simplemente imprime el carácter de en el campo [x] y luego hace el salto de línea. si no cumple sigue imprimiendo común y corriente